# Let $A = \{1, 3, 5, 9, 11, 13\}$ and let $\odot$ define the binary operation of multiplication modulo 14.

Tags: group-theory

Let $A = \{1, 3, 5, 9, 11, 13\}$ and let $\odot$ define the binary operation of multiplication modulo $14$.

Prove that $(A, \odot)$ is a group.

While completing this question I was able to show that the set was closed, and that associative law held, and that the set contained an identity element. However, I was unable to show that the set had inverses.

I drew up the following Cayley table for the set:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
\odot & 1 & 3 & 5 & 9 & 11 & 13 \\
1 & 1 & 3 & 5 & 9 & 11 & 13 \\
3 & 3 & 9 & 1 & 13 & 5 & 11 \\
5 & 5 & 1 & 11 & 3 & 13 & 9 \\
9 & 9 & 13 & 3 & 11 & 1 & 5 \\
11 & 11 & 5 & 13 & 1 & 9 & 3 \\
13 & 13 & 11 & 9 & 5 & 3 & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Any help with showing that this set has inverses would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There is a $1$ in every row, so every element $x$ has some element $y$ such that $x\odot y=1$. It is symmetric with respect to the diagonal. So, for that elements it also happens that $y\odot x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

There are only a handful of elements in $A$, so finding inverses is easily done by trial and error:
$$1^{-1}=1$$
$$3^{-1}=5\qquad5^{-1}=3$$
$$9^{-1}=11\qquad11^{-1}=9$$
$$13^{-1}=13$$

Answer (score 1):

To prove that any element has an inverse, find the element on the left column, and then search for a $1$ in its row. Then that shows there exists an element you can multiply it to give $1$, showing that it has an inverse.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can't believe I didn't realise that.